# Having issues displaying SVG in React application

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I have been trying to add in an SVG file in the same folder with the js file in my React application However it displays the no image default image. I am using the 1.6.9 react application

I've tried dragging and dropping in the content of the SVG file and I tried looking up solutions online with no luck.

```
<img src={"dot.svg"}/>
<img src={"./dot.svg"}/>
<smg src="./dot.svg">

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE svg 
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg width="100%" 
height="100%" viewBox="0 0 800 600" version="1.1" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" 
xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip- 
rule:evenodd;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke- 
miterlimit:1.5;"><ellipse cx="400" cy="300" rx="26.434" ry="25.114" 
style="fill:#00017f;stroke:#000;stroke-width:1px;"/></svg>
```

I would like to display the SVG file on my React Application.

Comment: It's in the same folder in the components folder in the src navbar --> components --> src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this,

```
<img src={require("./dot.svg")}/>
```

Or

More precisely [this](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files),

```
import dot from './dot.svg';

<img src={dot} />
```